# Surface integral over ellipsoid $ax^2+by^2+cz^2=1$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, surface-integrals

I'm not sure how to compute the integral
$$\int_{s} (a^2x^2+b^2y^2+c^2z^2)^{-1/2} d\vec{S}\cdot \vec{n}$$
over the surface of the ellipsoid
$$ax^2+by^2+cz^2=1$$, $$z>0$$

Where $\vec{n}$ is the unitary normal vector to the surface.

Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by $d\vec{S}\cdot \vec{n}$?

Comment: Do a change of variables (multiply or divide coordinates by $a,b,c$ or maybe their square roots) so that the integral is over the unit sphere instead of an ellipsoid.

Comment: The scalar field has $a^2, b^2, c^2 \, $ coefficients whereas ellipsoid has $a, b, c$. Is this how it is supposed to be? Please check.

Comment: Yes, that's how they put the excercise

Comment: @JeanMarie the problem is the integrand has $a^2$ whereas the surface has $a$. That is what I asked OP to confirm.

Comment: @Math Lover I see. I hadn't paid enough attention !

Comment: Let $f(x_1, x_2, x_3) = a x_1^2 + b x_2^2 + c x_3^2$. If we consider the full ellipsoid, then
$$\int_{f(x) = 1} \frac {dS} {|\nabla f(x)|} =
\int_{\mathbb R^3} \delta(1 - f(x)) \, dx =
\left. \frac d {dp}
 \int_{\mathbb R^3} H(p - f(x)) \, dx \hspace {1.5 px}
 \right\rvert_{p = 1} =
\left. \frac d {dp} \operatorname {Vol} (\mathcal E)
 \right\rvert_{p = 1},$$
where $\mathcal E$ is the solid bounded by an ellipsoid with principal semi-axis lengths $\sqrt {p/a}, \sqrt {p/b}, \sqrt {p/c}$. Compare with the [integral of $|\nabla f(x)|$](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3097407).

Answer (score 0):

We propose to attack the problem with a blunt instrument: on the surface
$$\vec{r}=\langle x,y,z\rangle=\left\langle x,y,\pm\sqrt{\frac{1-ax^2-by^2}{c}}\right\rangle$$
so
$$\begin{align}d\vec{r}&=\left\langle1,0,\mp\frac{\frac{ax}c}{\sqrt{\frac{1-ax^2-by^2}{c}}}\right\rangle\,dx+\left\langle0,1,\mp\frac{\frac{by}c}{\sqrt{\frac{1-ax^2-by^2}{c}}}\right\rangle\,dy\\
&=\left\langle1,0,-\frac{ax}{cz}\right\rangle\,dx+\left\langle0,1,-\frac{by}{cz}\right\rangle\,dy\end{align}$$
So that the vector areal element is
$$\begin{align}d^2\vec{A}&=\pm\left\langle1,0,-\frac{ax}{cz}\right\rangle\,dx\times\left\langle0,1,-\frac{by}{cz}\right\rangle\,dy\\
&=\pm\left\langle\frac{ax}{cz},\frac{by}{cz},1\right\rangle\,dx\,dy=\frac{\langle ax,by,cz\rangle}{c|z|}dx\,dy\end{align}$$
Then
$$\hat{n}=\frac{d^2\vec{A}}{\left\lVert d^2\vec{A}\right\rVert}=\frac{\langle ax,by,cz\rangle}{\left(a^2x^2+b^2y^2+c^2z^2\right)^{1/2}}$$
$$\begin{align}I&={\large\bigcirc}\kern-1.55em\iint_S\frac1{\left(a^2x^2+b^2y^2+c^2z^2\right)^{1/2}}\frac{\langle ax,by,cz\rangle}{\left(a^2x^2+b^2y^2+c^2z^2\right)^{1/2}}\cdot d^2\vec{A}\\
&=2\int_{-\frac1{\sqrt a}}^{\frac1{\sqrt a}}\int_{-\sqrt{\frac{1-ax^2}b}}^{\sqrt{\frac{1-ax^2}b}}\frac1{\left(a^2x^2+b^2y^2+c^2z^2\right)^{1/2}}\frac{\langle ax,by,cz\rangle}{\left(a^2x^2+b^2y^2+c^2z^2\right)^{1/2}}\cdot\frac{\langle ax,by,cz\rangle}{c|z|}dy\,dx\\
&=2\int_{-\frac1{\sqrt a}}^{\frac1{\sqrt a}}\int_{-\sqrt{\frac{1-ax^2}b}}^{\sqrt{\frac{1-ax^2}b}}\frac1{\sqrt c\sqrt{1-ax^2-by^2}}\,dy\,dx=2\int_{-\frac1{\sqrt a}}^{\frac1{\sqrt a}}\int_{-\frac{\pi}2}^{\frac{\pi}2}\frac1{\sqrt{bc}}\,d\theta\,dx=\frac{4\pi}{\sqrt{abc}}\end{align}$$
Where we have used the substitution
$$y=\sqrt{\frac{1-ax^2}b}\sin\theta$$
to solve the $y$-integral. Note that if $a=b=c$ then $a^2x^2+b^2y^2+c^2z^2=a$ on the surface and $d^2\vec{A}\cdot\hat{n}=d^2A$ and the integral is over the surface of a sphere of radius $1/\sqrt a$ so we should get
$$I=\frac1{\sqrt a}\frac{4\pi}{a}$$
so this checks.